# How to parse invalid JSON in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json

I want to parse a JSON Data which is invalid for Objective-C but this JSON is containing a valid JSON Array and a value after that seperated by "~".

My JSON is like this:

```
[
    {"id":"553",
    "parent_id":"0",
    "user_id":"0",
    "name":"testnav",
    "img_name":"8mS5ximage56.jpg",
    "img_path":"gallery/category/8mS5ximage56.jpg",
    "title":"",
    "description":"test",
    "position":"0",
    "status":"1",
    "update":"0",
    "app_id":"2",
    "multi":"0",
    "branch_id":"0"
    },
    {
    "id":"554",
    "parent_id":"0",
    "user_id":"0",
    "name":"test_Cat_for_iamgeUp",
    "img_name":"q5aW61.jpg",
    "img_path":"gallery/category/q5aW61.jpg",
    "title":"",
    "description":"desc",
    "position":"0",
    "status":"1",
    "update":"0",
    "app_id":"2",
    "multi":"0",
    "branch_id":"0"
    },
    {
    "id":"555",
    "parent_id":"0",
    "user_id":"0",
    "name":"test category",
    "img_name":"enSoW1.jpg",
    "img_path":"gallery/category/enSoW1.jpg",
    "title":"",
    "description":"desc",
    "position":"0",
    "status":"1",
    "update":"0",
    "app_id":"2",
    "multi":"0",
    "branch_id":"0"
    }
]~200
```

if I am trying to parse this through `NSJSONSerialization` method its giving error like `{NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}`.

Is there any way to capture that extra value and parse the JSON ?

Comment: Remove `~200` of your string, but more importantly, why do you have `~200` at the end? That's the real issue: server?

Comment: I can remove ~200 from the string but I don't have string , I have NSData got from server.

Comment: `NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:yourJSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSString *cleanJSONStr = //"remove the ~200 from jsonStr"; NSData *cleanJSONData = [cleanJSONStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSArray *yourReponse = [NSJSONSerialization ...:cleanJSONData ...];` ?

Comment: Yes, This is very helpful. Thanks @Larme

Comment: Excellent error message though!

Comment: Here is my code after successful jSON parsing

Comment: `NSError *parseError=nil;
NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataFromAPI encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *splitArray = [jsonStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"];
NSString *splittedValue = [splitArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSData *cleanJSONData = [[splitArray objectAtIndex:0] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *jSONData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:cleanJSONData options:0 error:&parseError];
if(parseError){
NSLog(@"Error on Parsing : %@",[parseError description]);
}else{
NSLog(@"JSON After Parsing : %@",jSONData);
}`

Answer (score 0):

The error is on the server side apparently. I'd strongly suggest to contact them in order that it gave PROPER JSON.
But, sometimes, you don't have control over them, or can't contact them, or they won't fix it now, and you still have work to do.

So, it's not the recommended way to do it, just a way to bypass your issue, since the response should be valid JSON, but in order to not keep getting stucked:

```
NSError *errorJSONSerialization = nil;
NSArray *yourResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: yourJSONData options:kNilOptions error:&errorJSONSerialization];
if (errorJSONSerialization) //Could it because because of the garbage at the end?
{
    NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:yourJSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    NSString *cleanJSONStr = //"remove the ~200 from jsonStr", there are various ways, according to how it may change: is it always ~200, or could it be in some case ~100, etc. 
    NSData *cleanJSONData = [cleanJSONStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    yourResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: cleanJSONData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
}
```